# Combining hide and show macros for grouped data in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create one macro combining two functions, to collapse and expand grouped rows of data.

The macros run individually. I want to combine them so I can assign to a button to check the True/False status of the ShowDetail property and overwrite the status respectively.

```vb
Sub Expand1()
    Rows(2).EntireRow.ShowDetail = True
End Sub

Sub Collapse1()
    Rows(2).EntireRow.ShowDetail = False
End Sub
```

I tried If Then logic.

When I execute the code Excel spits out

> runtime error 1004 :" the showDetail property cannot be changed.

```vb
Sub Colland()

    If Rows(2).EntireRow.ShowDetail = True Then
        Rows(2).EntireRow.ShowDetail = False
    Else: Rows(2).EntireRow.ShowDetail = True
    End If
    
End Sub
```

I'm guessing that I cannot change the property status because its the property being checked.

Comment: your code works fine, as long as row 2 is the summary row. If it is one of the rows to be collapsed, it will collapse fine but will throw that error on the next run.

Comment: thanks. So in order for it to run properly I need to choose a row that is above the one to be collapsed?

Comment: above or below, depending on which direction you are collapsing to. It must be a row that is showing a `-` sign (or `+` when collapsed)

Comment: Thank you. That was the mising piece of informartion. Have a great day :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the kind comments I was able to get the makro to execute properly
I also modified the code to target the active cell instead of a specific row and combined it with it being triggered when a range of cells are being clicked.

```
Sub Colland()

If ActiveCell.EntireRow.ShowDetail = True Then
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.ShowDetail = False
Else: ActiveCell.EntireRow.ShowDetail = True
End If

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Selection.Count = 1 Then
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A4:A85")) Is Nothing Then
        Call Colland
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

This works great for my intended purpose since I'm working with multiple groups of data  in between A4 and A85. Thanks @Paul